# Table Control Data persistence ASP.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm creating an asp.net/c# website and I'm having trouble with data persistence of a table control,

I have to add rows to the table dynamically from a set of textboxes several times, so, as is well known the http is stateless I'm saving the table content in the `Session` object every time I add a new row, then in the `page_load` event I try to retrieve the data from `Session` and adding it to the table, but it doesn't load again. I've debugged my code, and the table row count is increased in every postback, so I know my method works, but I have no idea why it does not render the table properly

Here's a simplified version of my code which shows my problem (it also does not work LOL)

```
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
    <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled" EnableViewState="False">
        <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableHeaderCell>
                Nombres
            </asp:TableHeaderCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
    </asp:Table>
</div>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Session["mtable"] != null)
            {
                Table1 = (Table)Session["mtable"];
            }
        }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        TableCell tc = new TableCell();
        tc.Text = TextBox1.Text;
        TableRow tr = new TableRow();
        tr.Cells.Add(tc);
        Table1.Rows.Add(tr);
        Session["mtable"] = Table1;
}
```

Please help, thanks

Comment: The Problem i'm having is that after my 2nd postback and so on, the table only render the row that i added in desing time (the table header cell)

Comment: If you just enabled viewstate on the table and didn't bother saving it to the session I think it would just work. Viewstate get's around the whole http is stateless problem, to a point, in a kind of nasty way.

Comment: i thought it would be, but when i detele the whole "session technique" and rely the persistance to the viewstate, the data is missed after a postback, it does not keep the row added previously, just load the one you are adding in the current submit

Answer (score 0):

Enabling viewstate would not change anything :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.table(v=vs.110).aspx

> It is important to remember that any programmatic addition or modification of table rows or cells will not persist across posts to the server. This is because table rows and cells are controls of their own, and not properties of the Table control. To persist any changes to the table, rows and cells must be reconstructed after each postback.

You have to rebuild your table. This way for example :

```
List<String> data = new List<String>();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["mtable"] != null)
    {
        data = (List<String>)Session["mtable"];
    }
    if (!IsPostBack) BuildTable();
}

protected void BuildTable()
{
    if (Session["mtable"] != null)
    {
        foreach (String s in data)
        {
            TableCell tc = new TableCell();
            tc.Text = s;
            TableRow tr = new TableRow();
            tr.Cells.Add(tc);
            Table1.Rows.Add(tr);
        }
    }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    data.Add(TextBox1.Text);
    Session["mtable"] = data;
    BuildTable();
}
```

If you have complex data, use a gridview and bind it to a datatable object that you can save in a Session variable.

Comment: well i'm pretty sure there's an easiest way to do it, but you helped me a lot to understand the concept, so, thank you very much